# Allowing only one negative in arrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have to read through an arrayList and throw an exception if there are any negative numbers, besides a -1 (which is expected in the list). I get how to look for negative numbers but I can't figure out how to allow the -1 in the list.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++){
    if(list.get(i) <= 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are throwing an exception when `<= 0`, not when `< -1`

Comment: if (list.get(i) < -1) should be enough

Comment: @cricket_007: I mean. This isn't a computing question but rather a basic algebra question.

Comment: Just change `if(list.get(i) < -1){`

Comment: Also `i <= list.size()` will throw an exception itself for `list.get(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with your code. First, you should stop the loop *before* `i` has the value `list.size()`. (Actually, since the index of the element is not used, you can use an [enhanced `for` loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with), which is what I show below.) Second, you need to test for the condition you want, not that each element is `<= 0`.

You don't say what kind of values are in the list. If they are integer types (say, `Integer`), then this should do it:

```
for (Integer val : list) {
    if (val < -1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

If they are floating point types (say, `Float`), you need a slightly more complicated test to screen for values like -0.5:

```
for (Float val : list) {
    if (val < 0 && val != -1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Also note that if the list can have `null` entries, you'd need to test for that as well (or document that the method will throw a `NullPointerException` for such a list).

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow one unique negative, you can inherit ArrayList :

```
public class MyArrayList<T extends Number> extends ArrayList<T> {

    private boolean hasNegative = false;

    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        if(t != null && t.floatValue() < 0) {
             if(hasNegative) {
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative element are not allowed anymore !");
             }
             hasNegative = true;
        }                 
        return super.add(t);
    }
}
```

To use it :

```
List<Integer> lst = new MyArrayList<Integer>();
lst.add(1);
lst.add(-1);
lst.add(3);
lst.add(-4); // Throw IllegalArgumentException because there is already -1
```

Comment: That's not going to work well if the list has floating point values. By using `intValue()`, entries like -0.5 will pass the test because `intValue()` will return 0.

Comment: Thks, that's right. I've edited with `doubleValue()`

Comment: Much better. Of course, `floatValue()` would work just as well for this, since `float` can represent -1 exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If negative values aren't ever allowed in the list, use a different list type

For example

```
class NonNegativeList extends ArrayList<Integer> {

    @Override
    public boolean add(Integer x) {
        if (x < -1) throw IllegalArgumentException();
        super.add(x);
    }   
}
```

As far as "Allowing *only one negative* in arrayList", add a boolean

```
class NonNegativeList extends ArrayList<Integer> {

    boolean negativeAdded;

    @Override
    public boolean add(Integer x) {
        if (x < -1) throw IllegalArgumentException();
        if (negativeAdded) return;
        if (!negativeAdded && x < 0) {
            negativeAdded = true;
        }
        super.add(x);
    }   
}
```

Comment: OP's problem seems to be to screen for bad values in a list that's passed as an argument. This is a nice way to define a list that rejects bad values to start with, but seems to not address OP's problem itself. (Of course, OP may be asking about an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)  Also, I don't see the "_only one negative_" quote in OP's question. Where did that come from?

Comment: @TedHopp The title.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - D'oh. I interpreted that to mean that only one negative value (-1) is allowed in the list, not that only one instance of one negative value is allowed. (I have this all the time with my wife; if there are two ways of understanding something, we always end up disagreeing.)